# SharePoint - After changing Item level permissions so that users will only see their items, how do managers/app rovers see everything?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

Good afternoon!

In an Sharepoint Approval List with Workflow, i have two groups with permissions. Employee Group (Contribute) and Manager Group (Design). I have set Item Level Permissions so that Employee can create and submit but not edit. The Managers can edit those items, select approve and submit.

Both Employees and Managers can only see what they created or edited. They don't see the full list of employee items. How do i get the Managers (Design Permissions) to see all of the employee items...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an out of the box feature you can turn on under list settings. Users that can create items only see their own and approved items, it was not clear from your post if approved items should be visible to all...

Require content approval & Versioning must be switched on for the bottom part to activate.

[image]

If the users should only see their own items, this setting under advanced might be a better choice. The design permission includes cancel checkout, so they will see all items.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Rune. Still no luck. I activated the content approval and versioning. I changed the ManagerGroup to Full Control. Still no luck. They don't see all of the entries...

Comment: This might only work for new items

Answer (score 0):

In the workflow, when item is created, you could change the permission of the current item:

1. set "Contribute" permission to "Created By"
2. set "Full Control" to Manager Group

   That's what we've done in Nintex workflow

Comment: Thank you for your response Matiur but the ManagerGroup has been changed to FullControl and still they are unable to see the full list. So just to be clear - Item-Level Permissions are set to 'Read items that were created by the user ' and 'Create items and edit items that were created by the user '  with those permissions how does the Manager Group be able to see all of the created entries?

Comment: For the existing items, you may manually trigger the workflow to update the permissions.  You can check the permission on a new item to see if the Manager Group has the "Full Control" to make sure workflow is doings its job